# IAuthorizationHandler as singleton gives me threading related issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In `startup.cs`, I have the below code line:

```
services.AddSingleton(IAuthorizationHandler, RoleBasedHandler>().cs
```

It gives an error in database operation and the error message says:

> A second operation started on this context before the previous
>   operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using
>   the same instance of DbContext.

When I changed that code line in `startup.cs`to:

```
services.Transient(IAuthorizationHandler, RoleBasedHandler>()
```

the error has gone. My understanding is that singleton version `RoleBasedHandler` creates only one `DbContext` object and it tries to reuse it in threads executing at the same time. `DbContext` object cannot work with more than one thread, therefore it breaks.

What is a best practice recommendation for my case?

Comment: How are you creating/requesting an instance of the `DbContext` class? Can you show the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need separate handlers and / or to make them use dbcontext per thread and not a single db context.

Not sure where this comes from - your handlers, are they prepackaged? That would indicate a major slip on whoever created them - as they are not thread safe from what you said.

Generally they should not be singletons.